# What is needed to write and test Android applications?

Tags: android

I want to write a small application (drag and drop). I have already integrated `Android SDK` with `Eclipse`. Will I need to have a smartphone to test it in real(if yes is a `Samsung Galaxy S5570` a good choice)? Or the emulator does the job? How do you do this?

Comment: I am new here and not already familiar whit "proper" behaviour. It's done now:) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emulator is more than enough to test your application when developing and especially if the app is something simple. If you want to make your app available to the public you **should** test your application on at least one phone. You can use your phone to test your app but you will not be able to test apps that have set in their `AndroidManifest` file a minimum sdk version of more then 8(because the phone is running `Froyo`).

Comment: I understand. The system can be updated to upper versions without any limitations?

Comment: @lunar The Samsung Galaxy S5570 can be officially upgraded to android 2.3(GingerBread) and of course there are many not-official possibilities like cyanogenmod, xda etc, i think that the only problem on further upgrading would be the hardware requirements. Of course as an android developer you should aim on targeting as many android sdk as possible and you should set you minimum sdk as low as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Real device is always preferrable to emulator.

Use emulator when you want to check something of your app doesn't really require performance, effects, memory usage, time consuming actions or accessible features...etc...for example: designing layout not really need a real device, but testing wifi requires a real device...

Anyway, a on-hand device for development is always the better choice.

Answer (score 2):

Any real phone is better to develop on than the emulator. The emulator is REALLY slow. As for the S5570, yes it's fine. Some might even argue that it's better to have a bad phone than a good phone because if your app works on a bad phone, it will probably run on a good phone. The contrary might not be equally true.